# Tensorflow Layers Api Linear Activation Function

Tags: python, tensorflow

This question is similar to this question: [How to use a linear activation function in TensorFlow?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36519724/how-to-use-a-linear-activation-function-in-tensorflow) however not the same.

On the final dense layer I want to output 28 nodes with a linear activation, not a sigmoid.  I am using the new layers api as shown here: https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/layers

My final layer stack looks like this however:

```
flat = tf.reshape(pool3, [-1, 128 * 128 * 128]) #width (after poolings), height (after poolings), filters
dense1 = tf.layers.dense(inputs=flat, units=4096, activation=tf.nn.relu)
dense2 = tf.layers.dense(inputs=dense1, units=4096, activation=tf.nn.relu)
dropout = tf.layers.dropout(
            inputs=dense2, rate=0.4, training=mode == learn.ModeKeys.TRAIN)
output = tf.layers.dense(inputs=dropout, units=28)
```

How does on ensure that the output of the 28 nodes is in fact linear?  In CNTK, you specify an activation function as None (see here: [cntk linear activation function in layers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41838154/cntk-linear-activation-function-in-layers) )

Pointers is greatly appreciated.  Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The [documentation of `dense`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/layers/dense) says about the `activation` parameter:

> `activation`: Activation function (callable). Set it to None to maintain a linear activation.

`None` is the default value, so not specifying the activation sets it to linear.

Comment: perfect; will give that a whirl.  Found later in the sample they are running a softmax and one hot, so this makes sense.